# Unable to get dom element inside JS object literal method

Tags: javascript, object-literal, iife

I was trying to refactor a simple JS plugin that I had created and after referring to various patterns in JS, i was able to make some good efforts considering that I'm a newbie in JS. The below code is the sample refactored one. But my "selectedDom" object returns null. Logically I'm unable to find the mistake. Please guide me in this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <style>
        .cross {
            background: red;
            width: 5px;
            height: 5px;
        }

        .input-field {
            height: 20px;
            width: 100px;
        }

        .input-area {
            height: 100px;
            width: 100px;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        var InputActions = (function () {
            "use strict";
            var options = {
                textVal: ".input-field",
                crossClass: ".cross",
                border: ".input-area",
                borderNone: "1px solid #e4e5e7",
                borderShow: "1px solid #006f9e"
            };

            function InputActions() {

            };
            InputActions.prototype = {
                selectedDom: document.querySelector(options.textVal),
                cross: function () {
                    var text = this.selectedDom.value;
                    var cross = document.querySelector(options.crossClass);
                    this.selectedDom.focus();
                    (text === "") ? cross.style.opacity = "0": cross.style.opacity = "1";
                },
                clearField: function () {
                    var input = this.selectedDom;
                    input.value = '';
                    this.cross();
                },
                focusItem: function () {
                    document.querySelector(options.border).style.border = options.borderShow;
                    this.cross();
                },
                blurItem: function () {
                    document.querySelector(options.border).style.border = options.borderNone;
                }
            };
            return InputActions;
        })();

        window.inputAct = new InputActions();
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="input-area cross">
        <input type="text" class="input-field" onclick="inputAct.focusItem()" />
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `this.selectedDom = this.selectedDom || document.querySelector(options.textVal); var text = this.selectedDom.value;`

Comment: You should not use a constructor + prototype approach when you have only a single instance and no instance properties at all. Use the module pattern, or restructure your code so that you can instantiate multiple `InputActions` by passing a (different) options object to each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you placed your `script` tag in `head` and it executed before `document.body` was even created.

To solve this problem you can move your `script` to the end of `body` or wrap it in function and execute it on [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) event.

---

If you wrap only instantiation part in `DOMContentLoaded` event handler then you have to move querying DOM to constructor body. So your code will look like

```
// ...
function InputActions() {
    this.selectedDom = document.querySelector(options.textVal);
};
InputActions.prototype = {
    cross: function () {
        var text = this.selectedDom.value;
// ...
```

And the DOMContentLoaded handler part:

```
document.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    window.inputAct = new InputActions();
});
```

Comment: `InputActions.prototype` is created while `document.body` don't exist and so is the `document.querySelector(options.textVal)` executed

Comment: Tried wraping it inside DOMContentLoaded by  function ready(){inputAct = new InputActions();}
  document.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", ready, false ); Still error persisted. The other approach of placing the script in body worked. Wondering why it didnt work in DOMContentLoaded

Comment: Again, it's because you create **prototype** of InputActions while `.input-field` doesn't exist. I think that `selectedDom` should be member of InputActions instance and not it's prototype.

Comment: Adding squint's code with your suggestion got the result. function InputActions() {
  this.selectedDom = this.selectedDom || document.querySelector(options.textVal); 
            }; function ready(){inputAct = new InputActions();}

  document.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", ready, false ); Like u mentioned in the prev comment @bgoscinski. It should be member of InputActions